# Writing to /tmp folder iPad

Tags: objective-c, sandbox, writetofile

I´m writing certain values to a file. See Write Operations below.
This works fine when using **iPad 6.1 Simulator**.

When trying the same thing on my iPad it fails. I think it´s something with sandboxing. I haven´t found out yet which path is best on iOS Devices to write stuff for internal use.

Any ideas?

```
#pragma mark Write Operations to Tmp Folder
    - (BOOL) psWriteFileWithName: (NSString*) fileName
                      withString:(NSString*) string {

        NSString *fileName = @"artistNumber";
        NSError * error = NULL;
        NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/tmp/%@.txt",fileName];
        [string writeToFile:filePath 
                 atomically:YES 
                   encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding 
                      error:&error];
        return  YES;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot write to `/tmp` since this is outside of your app sandbox.
However your app also has a temp directory, which can be referenced with the [`NSTemporaryDirectory()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000055-SW57) function:

Which works like:

```
NSString *tempfilePath =  [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
```

Here is you method with the correct [`NSTemporaryDirectory()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000055-SW57) implementation, also edit some error handling:

```
#pragma mark Write Operations to Tmp Folder
- (BOOL) psWriteFileWithName: (NSString*) fileName
                  withString:(NSString*) string {

    NSString *fileName = @"artistNumber";
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *filePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
    if (![string writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error] ) {
       NSLog(@"Error writing file: %@", error);
       return NO;
    }
    return  YES;
}
```

Comment: Great, that's what I was missing :)))

Comment: Also added some error handling to your code, so you can see what went wrong if the writing to file failed.

Comment: Oh, yes, thanks a lot. I haven´t been so far yet. Works great now ;)